# How do you measure voltage from first principles?

Tags: potential, voltage, measurements

I've always wondered if you were thrown back in time with just my cell phone, how could I charge it... I know how to make electricity, but how do I check the voltage if all I have access to is, shall we set the time at medieval tech?

So I'm guessing we start with a galvanometer, but how do I calibrate it, I know that 1 volt is 1 joule per electric charge of one coulomb, or 1 amp times 1 ohm, but how would I use that plus a very basic galvanometer to check that my lemon battery is 5volts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can take a CRC handbook back with you, there are certain wet cell chemistries that produce "well-known" and very stable output voltages. That would probably be your best starting point given the level of technology you're asking about.

For example, the [Clark cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_cell) and [Weston cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weston_cell) were historically used as voltage standards. The [Daniell cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_cell) might be simpler to build and will likely give you a good enough reference (at ~1.1 V) to use to charge a cell phone (which can likely tolerate at least +/- 10% or more variation of its input voltage).

Which cell chemistry is most convenient for you will depend on what minerals are available to you, which is why it's a good idea to take the whole CRC with you for reference, rather than just memorize the voltage produced by a couple of chemical combinations.